Where is Bill Currie's fork of DJASM available?
I'm looking for the CVS tree containing a fork of the DJASM assembler by Bill Currie.
https://www.delorie.com/djgpp/dl/ofc/current/v2/djdev205.zip/info/djasm.info has some information on it, but it doesn't have a working download link. How can I get this source tree?
Some more info about the CVS tree on https://www.delorie.com/archives/browse.cgi?p=djgpp-workers/2003/02/15/10:41:07 :

The files I listed are present in a snapshot of Bill Currie's independent
CVS tree for djasm.  I retrofitted some of his changes into our djasm,
but I stopped at the point where he split djasm.y into modules.

Thus I'm looking for a CVS tree containing multiple .c source files.

You could try emailing Bill Currie, the email address listed in he DJASM docs still appears to be valid (it appears recently in QuakeForge commits).

“CVS tree” as in the raw repository files? I doubt there is anyone (other than the author) who has that – CVS is not a distributed VCS.

@user3840170: Anybody who got a copy from the author many still have that copy. This is true for CVS and non-CVS repositories. For CVS, SVN and Git it's very eary to make a copy of the raw repository files, and use that copy as a repository somewhere else. What is not easy in CVS and SVN is merging changes between repositories. But I don't need that.

But people don’t usually make copies of whole CVS repositories. Checking one out downloads just a “working copy”, the latest version of each file. The raw repository files have to be made available over a separate protocol from CVS, and the host may choose not to do it at all; the upstream DJGPP certainly doesn’t.

Per your info file,

Some features described herein may be specific to Bill Currie's latest
version of `djasm', available at `www.taniwha.org', and may not (yet)
have found their way into the official DJGPP release.

archive.org has snapshots of www.taniwha.org dating back to 2000, including a djasm zip file.

That's a good start, but not what I'm looking for. I've updated the question.
